# Query supported languages for SpeechRecognizer using BroadcastReceiver intent

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, speech-recognition

I'm having trouble querying for supported languages using the SpeechRecognizer.ACTION_GET_SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES.

```
private void queryLanguages() {
    Intent i = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_GET_LANGUAGE_DETAILS);
    sendOrderedBroadcast(i, null);
}
```

Now, I know it says the BroadcastReceiver is specified in RecognizerIntent.DETAILS_META_DATA, but I'm not sure as to how I can access that.

So basically what I'm asking is how do I create an Intent to retrieve the available languages data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how it is done:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_GET_LANGUAGE_DETAILS);
    context.sendOrderedBroadcast(intent, null, new HintReceiver(),
                    null, Activity.RESULT_OK, null, null);
```

---

```
    private static class HintReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                if (DBG)
                    Log.d(TAG, "onReceive(" + intent.toUri(0) + ")");
                if (getResultCode() != Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    return;
                }
                // the list of supported languages. 
                ArrayList<CharSequence> hints = getResultExtras(true)
                        .getCharSequenceArrayList(
                                RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES);

        }
    }
```

Note :

> Whether these are actually provided is up to the particular implementation

Comment: I appreciate the code! It looks like there are a lot more languages now, even Pig-Latin! LOL