# No supported Languages for SpeechRecognizer on Android 8 Oreo

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo, android-speech-api

Querying for the system for supported SpeechRecognizer Languages using [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7870061/query-supported-languages-for-speechrecognizer-using-broadcastreceiver-intent) I've noticed that on Android 8 (Oreo) the returned results are empty. I've tested this on a Google Pixel and a Google Pixel C both running Android 8. It all works on all devices available to me running an Android version lower than 8. I couldn't find any changes to the way this is supposed to be done on Android 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coming back to answer my own question. Set the package of the Intent to `"com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox"` to receive the results for Android > 8.

A fix was discovered [in this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48653201/970998).

The actual issue (setPackage requirement) is discussed [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48653654/sendorderedbroadcast-setpackage-requirement-in-oreo).

An issue has been filed to [Google's Issue Tracker here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/73044965).