# RecognizerIntent.ACTION_GET_LANGUAGE_DETAILS in Oreo

Tags: java, android, speech-recognition, voice-recognition, google-voice-search

In most Android devices, the [RecognitionService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognitionService.html) will be supplied by Google's native 'Now/Assistant' application.

Up until Android Oreo, I was able to query the languages supported by the Google Recognizer with the following simple code:

```
final Intent vrIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_GET_LANGUAGE_DETAILS);

// vrIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox");

getContext().sendOrderedBroadcast(vrIntent, null, new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {

                // final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
                final Bundle bundle = getResultExtras(true);

                if (bundle != null) {

                    if (bundle.containsKey(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES)) {
                        Log.i("TAG", "onReceive: EXTRA_SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES present");

                        final ArrayList<String> vrStringLocales = bundle.getStringArrayList(
                                RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES);

                        Log.i("TAG", "onReceive: EXTRA_SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES size: " + vrStringLocales.size());

                    } else {
                        Log.w("TAG", "onReceive: missing EXTRA_SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES");
                    }

                } else {
                    Log.w("TAG", "onReceive: Bundle null");
                }

}, null, 1234, null, null);
```

However, since 8.0+ the extra `RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES` is no longer contained in the response.

Before I attempt to file this as a bug, I wanted to firstly see if others could replicate - but also check if there has been an Ordered Broadcast [behavioural change in API 26](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes.html) I've somehow overlooked, which could be the cause of this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried using [`getVoiceDetailsIntent()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognizerIntent.html#getVoiceDetailsIntent(android.content.Context))?

Comment: @azizbekian Thanks. I have - it just returns the shown intent of `RecognizerIntent.ACTION_GET_LANGUAGE_DETAILS`

Comment: Could you do simple debugging and verify, whether `Broadcast` is completed successfully by checking `getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK` or if `getResultData()` contains any value at the beginning of `receive()` function?

Comment: @R.Zagórski the result code matches the request code, in the above example 1234. The result data is null, but the documentation does state "This is often null". This behaviour is identical to pre-Oreo, which does contain the required language extra.

Comment: I've tested your code on Android Emulator with API 26 and I reach this `Log.i("TAG", "onReceive: EXTRA_SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES present");`. 

`compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "it.versionestabile.stackover001"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }` 

Do you say instead not reaching that code?

Comment: @shadowsheep thanks for testing. It doesn't reach that for me. Could you confirm you are running the most up to date version of Google Now/Assistant in the emulator please? It could be a versioning issue...

Comment: @brandall that's my version: `com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox, 7.2.29.21.x86`

Comment: @brandall `PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();

        for (PackageInfo packageInfo: packageManager.getInstalledPackages(0)) {
            if (packageInfo.packageName.contains("com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox"))
                Log.d("AAA", packageInfo.packageName + ", "  + packageInfo.versionName);
        }`

Comment: @shadowsheep thank you. Could you confirm the emulator config you are using please? If I can replicate, I'll let you know, so you can put your findings as an answer.

Comment: @brandall `Name: Nexus_5X_API_26_No_Proxy
CPU/ABI: Google Play Intel Atom (x86)
Path: C:\Users\***\.android\avd\Nexus_5X_API_26_No_Proxy.avd
Target: google_apis_playstore [Google Play] (API level 26)
Skin: nexus_5x
SD Card: 100M
hw.dPad: no
runtime.network.speed: full
hw.accelerometer: yes
hw.device.name: Nexus 5X
vm.heapSize: 256
skin.dynamic: yes
hw.device.manufacturer: Google
hw.gps: yes
hw.initialOrientation: Portrait
image.androidVersion.api: 26`

Comment: @brandall `hw.audioInput: yes
image.sysdir.1: system-images\android-26\google_apis_playstore\x86\
tag.id: google_apis_playstore
showDeviceFrame: yes
hw.camera.back: emulated
hw.mainKeys: no
AvdId: Nexus_5X_API_26_No_Proxy
hw.camera.front: emulated
hw.lcd.density: 420
avd.ini.displayname: Nexus 5X API 26 No Proxy
hw.gpu.mode: auto
hw.device.hash2: MD5:1be89bc42ec9644d4b77968b23474980
hw.ramSize: 1536
hw.trackBall: no
PlayStore.enabled: true
hw.battery: yes
hw.cpu.ncore: 4
hw.sdCard: yes
tag.display: Google Play
runtime.network.latency: none
hw.keyboard: yes`

Comment: @brandall `hw.sensors.proximity: yes
disk.dataPartition.size: 800M
hw.sensors.orientation: yes
avd.ini.encoding: UTF-8
hw.gpu.enabled: yes` and Android Studio 2.3.3

Comment: @brandall https://github.com/shadowsheep1/googlenowpackage

Comment: @shadowsheep really appreciate this. I'll come back to you when I've tested.

Comment: @brandall you are welcome!

Comment: @shadowsheep I can replicate! Thank you. Delving deeper into my code, it's a threading issue in Oreo. When I solve the exact cause, I'll let you know so you can post it as an answer and I'll award you the bounty!

Comment: @shadowsheep Could you confirm that if you comment out `vrIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox");` it then fails?

Comment: @brandall I confirm. Comment out `vrIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox");` it fails. I've tested also on a Mac OSX with Android Studio 3.0.1 and an emulator with API 27. Same behaviour. With the above line: OK. With the line commented out: KO.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164655/discussion-between-brandall-and-shadowsheep).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

So, I could't replicate, but further to the comments, if you don't set the package name

```
vrIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox");
```

then it fails, otherwise all works fine to me.

That's the basic activity I've used to test it.

```
package it.versionestabile.stackover001;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import static java.security.AccessController.getContext;

/**
 * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48500077/recognizerintent-action-get-language-details-in-oreo
 */
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final Intent vrIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_GET_LANGUAGE_DETAILS);
        vrIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox");

        PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();

        for (PackageInfo packageInfo: packageManager.getInstalledPackages(0)) {
            if (packageInfo.packageName.contains("com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox"))
                Log.d("AAA", packageInfo.packageName + ", "  + packageInfo.versionName);
        }

        this.sendOrderedBroadcast(vrIntent, null, new BroadcastReceiver() {

            @Override
            public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {

                // final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
                final Bundle bundle = getResultExtras(true);

                if (bundle != null) {

                    if (bundle.containsKey(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES)) {
                        Log.i("TAG", "onReceive: EXTRA_SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES present");

                        final ArrayList<String> vrStringLocales = bundle.getStringArrayList(
                                RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES);

                        Log.i("TAG", "onReceive: EXTRA_SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES size: " + vrStringLocales.size());

                    } else {
                        Log.w("TAG", "onReceive: missing EXTRA_SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES");
                    }

                } else {
                    Log.w("TAG", "onReceive: Bundle null");
                }
            }

            }, null, 1234, null, null);
    }
}
```

I've tested it both on Android Studio 2.3 and 3.0.1 and on emulator with API 26 and 27.

All works fine with the above code.

But if you comment out this line:

```
vrIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox");
```

on Oreo it doesn't work.

And I still suggest to check the presence of Google Now with Package Manager in a way like this:

PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();

```
for (PackageInfo packageInfo: packageManager.getInstalledPackages(0)) {
    if (packageInfo.packageName.contains("com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox"))
        Log.d("AAA", packageInfo.packageName + ", "  + packageInfo.versionName);
// TODO - set a boolean value to discriminate the precence of google now
}
```

In order to decide if you have the right version of Google Now.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I'll be posting another question to try and work out why in Oreo you need to specify the package name... Thank you once again!

Comment: For comparison, how should it look like prior to OREO ? thanks

Comment: @RonTLV prior to Oreo it works also without explicitly setting the package to the intent.

Comment: Best solution, I tested in Android 9 and it works. I have only added the line "setPackage("com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox")" to my Intent and it worked.
Thanks